# Speeding up a fan running in 'dumb' mode

Tags: power-supply, fan

I'm looking for feedback about how to get a computer cooling fan to spin with higher RPM.  (It's a fully 'dumb' connection - this is a 120mm fan in an under-the-desk air purifier, so no thermostat or CPU control).  This was the sort of fan that the manufacturer used - but that fan was really noisy and I'm replacing it with a quieter fan.

The replacement fan is a 3pin fan, but also had a 'hard drive' style power connector that only used two wires (red/black).  So, I do know that the manufacturer didn't get clever - it's a fan that can be controlled (yellow wire+red/black) OR run without control (red/black).  The air filter has a 2pin header, and I snipped and soldered to old 2pin connector in its place.

So, as things stand, the fan has a replacement 2pin connector on it, and is plugged into the power supply and spinning.  But it's spinning a lot slower than I'd like.

So, can anyone suggest a way to get the fan to spin faster?  I figured that I'd ask here since someone has probably done something similar on their computer's case fans.  Thanks!

Comment: The first thing I'd try is entering my motherboard BIOS. Depending on the motherboard, you may be able to control the fan from there. You have indicated that your fan is plugged into the power supply but I'm going to assume you mean into the motherboard.

Comment: Thanks, but no - it's a purely dumb supply (no MOBO, just a little power connection).  I kind of suspect that it's not something that I can change without getting another fan (different number of windings, etc.) but I'm hoping that someone has a more immediate idea than buying yet another fan.

Comment: Increase the voltage, it will spin faster - up until the point it burns out. As we don't know what the old supply was, or what the new supply is, or what the fan actually wants… that's the best guess.

Answer (score 0):

you can purchase a fan that spins faster.  you can choose the size, voltage, pin count and type of connector.  faster fans are generally louder if that is a concern.